# C# Compact Framework 3.5 generics problem

Tags: c#, .net, generics, compact-framework

```
public class Canvas<T> : Slidable where T : IItem 
{
```

This code fails with.

> Error 5   genasm.exe(1) : error There was an error finalizing type .
>   GenericArguments[0], 'Smart.Controls.ButtonItem', on
>   'Smart.Controls.Canvas`1[T]' violates the constraint of type parameter
>   'T'.  Smart

If i remove the Where constraint it is fine.

ButtonItem definition..

```
public class ButtonItem : ButtonStyle,IItem, ISkinable
```

I dont know whats going on..

**UPDATE**

```
public class TabHeader : Canvas<ButtonItem>
```

I think that this is causing the problem

Comment: Do both references to `IItem` refer the the same namespace?

Comment: Yes, however i believe that the problem is not there but (in updated question)

Comment: Can you post the whole classes and interface structure ?!

Comment: So what happens if you make it `TabHeader : Canvas<IItem>`

Comment: Same error except that Smart.Controls.ButtonItem becomes Smart.Controls.IItem in error message

Comment: i think that it is a designer issue although i dont have a designer...cause i get a warning first the base class ... could not be loaded....